# Одинаковый Рандом

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Использую метод, для того, чтобы сгенерировать последовательность нулей и едениц:

```
static public string Generate(int count)
{
    string WritedString = "";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (WritedString.Length < count)
    {
        int random = rnd.Next(1, 3);
        if (random == 1)
        {
             WritedString = WritedString + "1";
        }
             else
        {
             WritedString = WritedString + "0";
        }
    }
    return WritedString;
}
```

Этот метод вызывается около 120-ти раз в цикле, и вот что выводит консоль(значение count рандомно):[image: Вывод в консоль]

У меня такое ощущение, что так быть не должно. Как исправить?

---

Для тех, кто не может: замените и читайте "случайно" или 
"рандомно" на "псевдо рандомно".

Comment: Перенесите инициализацию внутрь цикла.

Comment: Ссылка на дубликат совсем про другое...Там речь про сид была.

Comment: @Suvitruf у автора метод 120 раз в цикле вызывается, и создает 120 рандомов, которые периодически попарно одинаковые. Как вы думате, почему так? :)

Comment: @tym32167 если он вынесет создание экземпляра вне метода, то не будет такой проблемы.

Comment: @Suvitruf Так ссылка именно про эту проблему, почитайте ответ там

Comment: Попробуй перед каждым вызовом рандома вызывать
Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);